# File handling in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to open file in append mode in blackberry? In Connector class there are constants READ, WRITE, READ_WRITE but I didn't find any constant for append mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, though it isn't a separate mode:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(pathToFile, Connector.READ_WRITE);
OutputStream out = fc.openOutputStream(fc.fileSize());
// Now you can write to the output stream and it will append to the end of the file
```